# How create calculator in linux script?

Tags: shell-script, string

I am trying to create a calculator:

```
echo "What is your number?"
read n1 

echo "what is your second number?"
read n2

echo "what do you want to do?"
echo "1. add"
echo "2. subtract"
echo "3. divide"
echo "4. multiply"
read ans


if 
ans=$(( $n1+$n2 )); then
echo $ans

elif
ans=$(( $n1-$n2 )); then
echo $ans

elif
ans=$(( $n1/$n2 )); then
echo $ans

elif
ans=$(( $n1*$n2 )); then
echo $ans

else
```

But when I insert letters it shows me 0.
How can I improve it? Also it gives me sometimes wrong answers.

Comment: You don't employ the `$sign` variable anywhere... And you would be better off using a `case` statement than all that `if..elif...` logic.

Comment: **ok I changed it ans**

Comment: You certainly can do this.  However, you'd be much better off using a high-level scripting language like Python for this sort of thing.

Comment: **Just use [the basic calculator, `bc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html).**  No need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `while loop` :

```
input="yes"
while [[ $input = "yes" ]]
do

    PS3="Press 1 for Addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication and 4 for division: "
    select math in Addition Subtraction Multiplication Division
    do
        case "$math" in
        Addition)
            echo "Enter first no:"
            read num1
            echo "Enter second no:"
            read num2
            result=`expr $num1 + $num2`
            echo Answer: $result
            break
        ;;
        Subtraction)
            echo "Enter first no:"
            read num1
            echo "Enter second no:"
            read num2
            result=`expr $num1 - $num2`
            echo Answer: $result
            break
        ;;
        Multiplication)
            echo "Enter first no:"
            read num1
            echo "Enter second no:"
            read num2
            result=`expr $num1 * $num2`
            echo Answer: $result
            break
        ;;
        Division)
            echo "Enter first no:"
            read num1
            echo "Enter second no:"
            read num2
            result=$(expr "scale=2; $num1/$num2" | bc)
            echo Answer = $result
            break
        ;;
        *)
            echo Choose 1 to 4 only!!!!
            break
        ;;
    esac
    done

done
```

Comment: Some questions about this one: 1) Why the `input=yes; while [[ $input = "yes" ]]` instead of `while true`? 2) Why the `while...` with all the `break`s. When all the `break`s are removed you can get rid of the whole `while...` routine. And, BTW, Multiplication should be `expr $num1 \* $num2`

Comment: And in addition to the answer, the OP asks also about entering non-numeric characters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash to deal with that.

Comment: @terdon, I understand the script and therefore the underlying question why to use `break` and circumvent that with the `while` loop. The manual already mentions that '*The list is executed after each selection until a `break` command is executed*'. To clean up the code you could get rid of the breaks and the enclosed while loop.

Comment: @Lambert oh! You're quite right, my mistake. I am not very familiar with `select`.

Comment: If you think of further improving it just check out zenity. So you can make GUI for it out of shell script itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
clear
sum=0
i="y"

echo " Enter one no." 
read n1 
echo "Enter second no."
read n2

while[ $i = "y" ]
do 
echo "1.Addition" 
echo "2.Subtraction" 
echo "3.Multiplication" 
echo "4.Division" 

echo "Enter your choice" 
read ch 

case $ch in 
1)sum=`expr $n1 + $n2` 
   echo "Sum ="$sum;; 

2)sum=`expr $n1 - $n2` 
   echo "Sub = "$sum;; 

3)sum=`expr $n1 \* $n2` 
   echo "Mul = "$sum;; 

4)sum=`expr $n1 / $n2` 
    echo "Div = "$sum;; 

*)echo "Invalid choice";; 
esac 

echo "Do u want to continue ?" 
read i 
if [ $i != "y" ] then
      exit 
fi 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simpler one.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter first number"
read p
echo "enter second number"
read q
echo  "enter the  operator"
read r
sum=`expr $p "$r" $q`
echo  "the total" $sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash  
#arithmetic calculator using command line arguement  

if [ $# -eq 3 ]  
then  
x=`echo "scale=3; $1 $2 $3" |bc -l`  
echo "answer is: $x"  
else  
echo "Invalid statement"  
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "Enter Your Choise : "
echo "1.Addition"
echo "2.Substtaction"
echo "3.Multiplication"
echo "4.Division"
read opr
echo "Enter first Number : "
read n1
echo "Enter second Number : "
read n2
if [$opr=1] then
  echo `expr ans=$((n1+n2))`
elif [$opr=2] then
  echo `expr ans=$((n1-n2))`
elif [$opr=3] then
  echo `expr ans=$((n1*n2))`
else [$opr=4] then
  echo `expr ans=$((n1/n2))`
```

Comment: At the first glance `if`  statement should be ended with `fi`, and after `[` should be space, `else` should not contain conditional statement.  Test your scripts before posting.